# Facebook like button will not show

Tags: facebook-like

I am trying to add a facebook like button following the instructions https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button
but it will not show. I have even put the code in an empty html document but it still doesn't work.
Any help greatly appreciated, it is driving me mad!
Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>facebook like</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />



</head>

<body>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://mdolbear.com/" data-width="200" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="true"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you testing this locally via file system, or via HTTP?

Comment: i'm testing locally  but have an internet connection so it should work.. I just dont see what i am missing.

Comment: If you are not using HTTP(S) to access your test pages, then `js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/…` can’t work. You can place `http:` in there to make it an address the browser can resolve in such a case, `js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/…`

Comment: I have added http: into my code but there is still no button appearing :(